# Migrate sybase 11.5 to 12.5.4

Tags: database, sybase, dump, migrate, ase

I would like migrate a database of sybase ASE 11.6 to a other server sybase ASE 11.9.2(ssma), 12.5.4 or later

I don't find a way to do that, i try to dump a database from 11.6 like that:

```
 sp_dboption '<dbname>','single user',true
 go
 use <dbname>
 go
 dump database <dbname> to '/usr/dumps/remote/ledump.dmp'
```

and load on 12.5.4 like that: 
sp_dboption '','single user',true
go
use 
go
dump database  to '/tmp/dump.dmp'

Then go to ASE 12.5.4

```
  sp_dboption '<dbname>','single user',true
  go
  load database hr_db from '/tmp/ledump.dmp'
```

Database is offline !
then

```
online database REFCOM
go
```

database still offline !
the error: database is not ready yet

After shutdown server and restart, database is here but i have no table, juste user, role and procedure

I have some other option: ddlgen (not work on 11.6 i think), linked server ?, syscomment :@.

If someone have an idea to how migrate this database, it's will be a great help for me.

i find some technical help on ASE 10-11: http://www.nowandfutures.com/sybase/
and  http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_12.5.1/title.htm

thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, 11.6 -> 12.5.4 would not be directly supported.  I believe you can go from 11.6 -> 12.0 -> 12.5.4 or 11.6 -> 11.9.2 -> 12.5.4, but once you get more than 2 major releases apart, it's not supported.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, a dump or a ddlgen is not support between 11.6 to 12.5.4 ? I think ddlgen not work on 11.6 and dump work but not realy good, i have user, role, procedure, but i haven't tables and views.

Comment: I'm not sure about DDL gen, I didn't start working with Sybase until 11.9.2, but the dump works well if it's between supported versions.

Comment: Ok, thank you, finally, i use system table (syscomments ( procedure, view, trigger..), sysobjects, syscolumns and sysindexes (tables)) to generate the scripts.